# Collect data from three table in yii1?

Tags: yii, cactivedataprovider

I am new in `YII1`. I have three tables: `Jd`, `jda` and `user`. Relation with `jd` and `jda` is

```
'jobDescription'=> array(self::HAS_MANY, 'JobDescriptionAssignment', /*array('id'=>'job_desc_id')*/'id'),
```

and the relation between `jda` and `user` is

```
'users' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
```

My tables are :

> jd->id,name
>     jda->id,jd_id,user_id
>     user->id,supervisor_id

`supervisor_id` comes from user table id. Now I want to show data from `jd` model those user whose `supervisor_id` is logged in id.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, what are you asking for help with?  Setting up the relation, querying the active record, etc?  The answer also changes with the version of yii - 1/2.

Comment: Now you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

see this topic [Yii Framework : Join table (or other SQL) in data provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176303/yii-framework-join-table-or-other-sql-in-data-provider)

```
public function search(){

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
    $criteria->compare('createDate',$this->createDate,true);
    $criteria->compare('updateDate',$this->updateDate,true);
    $criteria->compare('remark',$this->remark,true);
    $criteria->with = array('cateLang' => array(
        'condition' => 'cateLang.id = 1 OR cateLang.id = 2',
        'order' => 'cateLang.id ASC'
    ));

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

-

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'category-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        array(
            'name' => 'FrenchTitle'
            'value' => '(isset($data->cateLang[0])) ? $data->cateLang[0]->name : "no Title"',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'EnglishTitle'
            'value' => '(isset($data->cateLang[1])) ? $data->cateLang[1]->name : "no Title"',
        ),
        'createDate',
        'updateDate',
        'remark',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: ps: you can join more tables